# python reload() not having any effect?

Tags: python, module

I have a hbase.py file in the pyspark directory.  Inside the REPL I attempt to reload it:

```
>>> reload(pyspark.hbase)
<module 'pyspark.hbase' from '/shared/hwspark2/python/pyspark/hbase.py'>
>>> from pyspark.hbase import *
>>> # run the code .. latest changes not apparent..
```

No error .. however, the definitions of the classes were not updated - as evidenced by new print statements not appearing.

After exiting the interpreter and reloading the module, the updates are visible. Yet once again any further changes to the module are not visible even after calling reload.

Comment: Are you creating new instances of those classes and using those, or are you trying to use existing instances after the `reload`?

Comment: Can you give us a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (akin to the one in my answer) of what you mean? It's hard to understand what you mean by "the definitions of the classes were not updated", especially if (as seems likely) the entire problem is that you (like most people) don't understand how Python classes really work under the covers and are expecting them to do something they can't possibly do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three possibilities come to mind (one is @abarnert's):

- `pyspark.hbase` has an `__all__`, and the classes you are trying to use are not in it
- `pyspark.hbase` does not have an `__all__`, but your class names / functions / etc. begin with an `_`.
- you are not recreating your class instances after the reload, so they are still tied to the old module's classes.

`__all__` is used as a way for a module to define its official API.  It is also used to provide a list of names to import when a `from ... import *` is issued.  If `__all__` is not defined, then any name in the module that does not start with an `_` will be loaded when `from ... import *` is used on that module.

Whether or not `__all__` is defined you can always explicitly load any name defined in the module by asking for it directly:

```
from xyz import _private
```

will load `_private` into your module's namespace.

Comment: I have no knowledge of the __all__ so anything there is well fair game. Your second bullet point *seems* to apply here - we have a few attributes that start with _  Does that mean an __all__ were required? Care to add a code snippet? thanks.

Comment: OK i found some examples. This was quite helpful.

Comment: I don't think either of the first two can be the issue. Sure, `reload` won't load private classes… but the initial `from … import *` wouldn't have loaded them either, so they can't matter in the first place.

Comment: @abarnert:  the OP could have loaded the private members explicitly and not realized that `reload` would not reload them.

Comment: I suppose that's not _impossible_, but it seems pretty unlikely, especially given the level of knowledge implied by his question and comments. Someone who wouldn't even think of this possibility, and didn't understand your answer as originally written, wouldn't have known to `from spam import _eggs` before the `reload`.

Comment: @abarnert: Unlikely or not, judging from his comments to both our answers it seems to be what happened.

Comment: @EthanFurman: No, I think he just doesn't understand what happened; he has a few attributes that start with `_`, and therefore he thinks he needs to add an `__all__`, and… that's just not even on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear from the question, but I think you're misunderstanding what [`reload`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#reload) does.

It re-imports the module, including all of the new class objects defined in it, and it changes `sys.modules[name]` to refer to that new module object, and it also copies the name to your globals.

But that's *all* it does. It doesn't automatically find every reference to the old module, much less to anything defined in the old module, etc., and fix them all up to refer to the replacement versions. (How could it? There might not even *be* a replacement version in the new module. For that matter, what if you had values that were calculated by the old code and would be calculated differently; it would have to re-run everything you'd done since importing the module.)

The documentation (linked above) explains it in different terms, but let's make this concrete, so I can explain it more directly.

Create this file:

```
# mod.py
class Spam(object):
    def eggs(self):
        print('spam spam spam spam')
```

Now:

```
$ python
>>> import mod
>>> spam = mod.Spam()
>>> spam.eggs()
spam spam spam spam
```

Now let's edit it:

```
# mod.py
class Spam(object):
    def eggs(self):
        print('out of spam!!!')

>>> reload(mod)
>>> spam.eggs()
spam spam spam spam
>>> morespam = mod.Spam()
>>> morespam.eggs()
out of spam!!!
>>> type(spam) is type(morespam)
False
```

When you create `spam` by calling `mod.Spam()`, that looks up `'mod'` in globals, then looks up `'Spam'` in the resulting module, then calls its constructor and initializer, giving you an object whose `__class__` is a reference to that `mod.Spam` class.

When you call `spam.eggs()`, Python looks up `'spam'` in the global dictionary, looks up `'eggs'` in that `spam` object's dictionary, then, failing that, looks up `'eggs'` in the `spam.__class__` object's dictionary. As we know, that's the `mod.Spam` object, which has an `eggs` method, so that gets called.

Now, after we `reload(mod)`, there's a new object called `'mod'`, and it has a new class called `'Spam'` as a member. But the old `mod` and `mod.Spam` objects—and, for that matter, your `spam`—still exist. And the existing `spam` still has a reference to the old `mod.Spam` in its `__class__`. So, when you call `spam.eggs()` the second time, the exact same thing happens as before. Python looks up `'spam'` as a global, looks up `'eggs'` first in `spam` and then in `spam.__class__`, finds the same class as before, and calls the same function as before.

When we construct `morespam` by calling `mod.Spam()` again, now that looks up `'mod'` in globals and finds the new `'mod'`. It then looks up `'Spam'` in that module and finds the new class. So, we've got an instance whose `__class__` is the new `mod.Spam`. When we call its `eggs` method, the same thing happens as above, but now it's the new function that gets called.

---

Using `from mod import *` instead of `import mod` makes things a little harder to understand, but the basic idea is the same. The `from mod import *` doesn't put `mod` into your globals, and instead copies all of its non-private globals (anything listed in `mod.__all__`, or, if no such thing exists, anything in `mod` that doesn't start with a single underscore) to your globals. So, the `reload` creates a new module object, and the second `from mod import *` copies all of that new module's non-private globals into your globals, replacing the old ones. But your `spam` instance is still an instance of the old `Spam`, not the new one.